# Confused about enolate chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, esters, elimination

I'm not so sure how this mechanism is supposed to go. Could anyone provide some pointers?

[image]

The answer is supposed to be:

[image]

In particular, I'm confused about how to break up the two esters.

Comment: Google “malonic ester synthesis”, there might be a few helpful pages.

Comment: What do you know about the stability of 1,3-dicarboxylic acids?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19410/decarboxylation-under-acid-water-and-extreme-heat